# Reliability of using a PendingIntent to store application state

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have a Service that first creates a new Intent, and calls `setAction('foo')` on it. After this I call `putExtra("key","value123")`.  Then I call `PendingIntent.getService(this,999,intent,0)` (no flags passed), and pass the pending intent to the AlarmManager.

But then before the alarm fires (or even after, it seems) I create another Intent and again call `setAction('foo')` on it, but don't set any extras.
Then I again pass it to `PendingIntent.getService(this,999,intent,0)`.  However, this time I call `send()` on the PendingIntent so as to receive the intent immediately.

What I observe is that the original extras are delivered with the new Intent.  I appear to be able to do this over and over, and even if my app is killed, when I restart it, the extras are still there.

However, I don't see anything specifically in the documentation which says whether or not this is actually expected behavior.  Is this a reliable method by which I can persist a small amount of data in RAM (only!) in case my app gets terminated?  Currently I'm using file on a RAMdisk, but some devices apparently don't have such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way `PendingIntent` works ;-)

The first call to `PendingIntent.getService()` creates a new `PendingIntent` with the `requestCode` set to 999 and the `Intent` set to `ACTION="foo"`.

The second call to `PendingIntent.getService)` doesn't create a new `PendingIntent`. It just returns a token (reference) to the first `PendingIntent`. When you call `send()` on it, the original `PendingIntent` is sent.

The reason is that when you call `PendingIntent.getService()`, Android first tries to find a `PendingIntent` that matches the one you've specified. To determine if the `Intent` matches, it checks the ACTION, COMPONENT, DATA and it also checks for matching `requestCode` arguments. In your case, both calls to `PendingIntent.getService()` have the same `requestCode` and the `Intent`s have the same ACTION. **NOTE: "extras" in the `Intent` are not considered when determining if the `Intent`s match**.

If you always want to (re)use a single `PendingIntent` and just override the "extras" every time you use it, you can add the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to the call to `PendingIntent.getService()`.

If you need to create several `PendingIntent`s in parallel, with different "extras", you need to make sure to use a unique `requestCode` every time you call `PendingIntent.getService()`.

Comment: ok. a bit more experimenting suggests that if the PendingIntent isn't registered with the AlarmManager, under some conditions the extras data is lost.  I haven't seen this ever occur when it is registered, so the only gap is whether I can always get the extras from a registered PendingIntent by calling getService with the same parameters and doing an immediate send().  Seems to always work, but is it guaranteed?

Comment: If you pass the `PendingIntent` to another process, then Android will keep the `PendingIntent` (with its "extras") in its internal database. If you create a `PendingIntent` but don't do anything with it, then Android will delete it as there are no active references to it. That being said, saving data in a `PendingIntent` is not a replacement for using `SharedPreferences` or some other persistent storage. Also realize that if the phone restarts, all the `PendingIntent`s are lost.

Comment: Thanks David.  Losing state on restart is fine; my concern is I need my `Service` to always have latest state available to the `Activity` on request.  If the service gets killed, it can't always re-create previous state right away (it often must wait until new sensor data is received, which might take a while).  Persistence (beyond RAM) is inappropriate due to high refresh rate of state that often won't even be used (it would be a waste of battery and flash erase cycles).  From what I can tell, the internal database you mention is RAM only, which is ideal for my use case.